# how to verify text color in Robot Framework Wait Until Page Contains?

Tags: robotframework

I wanted to verify the text is in red color at android native app.

I inspect the element but there is not indicator mention about font color.

how do I verify them like below keyword?

```
Wait Until Page Contains            'text is ABC and in red'
```

Comment: @gua robotframework might be not visual testing

Comment: any recoomendation tool?